# Complex Triangle inequality

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

Given that

$|z_1| = |z_2| = 1 $

How would I use the triangle inequality to prove

$|z_1 + 1|+|z_2+1|+|z_1z_2+1|\geq|z_1+1|+|(z_2+1)-(z_1z_2+1)|$

And

$|z_2-z_1z_2| = |1-z_1|$

Comment: **Hint :** $|A| + |B| \ge |A+B|.$

Comment: Why do you believe this is a complex Triangle inequality ?

Comment: I was told, I asked the question last night without realising it was a duplicate, when i was directed to the original post the second line gave no explanation to why it was that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $|a|=|-a|$ and that $|b|+|a| \geq |b+a|$ so

$$|z_2+1|+|z_1z_2+1|\geq|(z_2+1)-(z_1z_2+1)|$$

And for the second $$|z_2-z_1z_2| = |z_2(1-z_1)|= |z_2||1-z_1| = 1\cdot |1-z_1|$$